# The cleveref capitalize option does not seem produced capitalized output

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

Whether I use the `\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}` or `\usepackage{cleveref}`, I don't see any difference in the output from `\cref`.  Do I understand correctly that this option is indented to force `\cref` to output the capitalized version of the environment name, even if not at the beginning of a sentence?

Here is the LaTeX file I'm using.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}


\theoremstyle{plain}% default
\newtheorem{prototheorem}{Theorem}[section]
\colorlet{shadecolor}{orange!15}

\newenvironment{theorem}
   {\begin{shaded}\begin{prototheorem}}
   {\end{prototheorem}\end{shaded}}

\newtheorem{protolemma}[prototheorem]{Lemma}
\newenvironment{lemma}
   {\begin{shaded}\begin{protolemma}}
   {\end{protolemma}\end{shaded}}

\newtheorem{protocorollary}[prototheorem]{Corollary}
\newenvironment{corollary}
   {\begin{shaded}\begin{protocorollary}}
   {\end{protocorollary}\end{shaded}}

\crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
\Crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}
\Crefname{lemma}{Lemma}{Lemmas}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
  \label{ent.201}
  If $V$ is a set of subsets of $U$, and $\exists X_0 \in V$ such that
  $X \in V$ implies $X_0 \subseteq X$, then $X_0 = \bigcap V$.
\end{lemma}

Intuitively, \cref{ent.201} says that given a set of subsets,
if one of those subsets happens to be a subset of all the given
subsets, then it is in fact the intersection of
all the subsets.

\begin{theorem}
  \label{ent.188}
  If $V \subseteq U$, and if $F$ is a set of binary functions defined on
  $U$, then there exists a unique $clos_F(V)$, and it is closed under $F$.
\end{theorem}

We can see from \cref{ent.201} and also from
\cref{ent.188} such sets are always finite.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Which version of cleveref do you use?

Comment: With the code I get 'Lemma 0.1' and 'Theorem 0.2'. Both with capital letters. Can you show a screenshot of the output you get? What version of `cleveref` are you using? Add `\listfiles` to the beginning of your file and check the `.log` to find out. Mine is `cleveref.sty    2018/03/27 v0.21.4`.

Comment: My version is
cleveref.sty    2018/03/03 v0.21.3 Intelligent cross-referencing

Comment: hmmm, works fine for me now.   I was compiling with pdflatex.   Could that be a problem?

Comment: It should not be a problem to use pdfLaTeX. I compiled your MWE with pdfLaTeX as well.

Comment: Can we close this question then?

Comment: Yes it can be closed.   I don't see a close link anywhere.